# Get id or name of Azure Webjob run when triggered externally

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

when I start a webjob using the rest api :
/api/triggeredwebjobs/{job name}/run?arguments={arguments}

I need to know if the program invoked ran successfully or not and for now I request the latest result from the history using .../api/triggeredwebjobs/{job name}/history

Now, is there a way to get the {id} of the Job just after I invoke ? Because obviously there's no way to be sure that the latest history is the job I just ran. Or is there another way to get things done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, we added a new binder in the extensions library to allow you to get the instance ID - **ExecutionContext**. See an [example here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/master/src/ExtensionsSample/Samples/MiscellaneousSamples.cs#L17) in the extensions repo samples. To use this binding you'll have to pull in the beta1 Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions prerelease package, and add config.UseCore() to your startup code (as the sample app shows). This was added based on another ask similar to yours.

Comment: Yes you're correct - the answer I gave above was for WebJobs that are using the WebJobs SDK, and the ID it returns is the WebJobs SDK invocation ID, not the ID you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can call this anywhere in your code and it works !
(Not in debug, but when published)

```
Console.Out.WriteLine("RUN NAME : " + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBJOBS_RUN_ID"));
```

Comment: See my new answer, which might be interesting to you as well if you needed the same as OP.

Answer (score 2):

We just added support for this in the WebJobs API. The way it works is that when you send the POST request to trigger the WebJob, you now get back a location attribute, with a URL to the details of the run that was started. e.g.

```
Location: https://mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/SomeJob/history/201605192149381933
```

You can then query this URL to track the run, e.g.

```
{
  "id": "201605192149381933",
  "name": "201605192149381933",
  "status": "Success",
  "start_time": "2016-05-19T21:49:38.1933956Z",
  "end_time": "2016-05-19T21:49:39.4826458Z",
  "duration": "00:00:01.2892502",
  "output_url": "https://mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/vfs/data/jobs/triggered/SomeJob/201605192149381933/output_log.txt",
  "error_url": null,
  "url": "https://mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/SomeJob/history/201605192149381933",
  "job_name": "SomeJob",
  "trigger": "External - ARMClient/1.1.1.0"
}
```